# Find the limit: $\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{x^{\sqrt{\ln x}}\cdot(\sqrt{\ln x})^x}{(\sqrt{x})^{\ln x}\cdot(\ln x)^{\sqrt{x}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

Find the limit :

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{x^{\sqrt{\ln x}}\cdot(\sqrt{\ln x})^x}{(\sqrt{x})^{\ln x}\cdot(\ln x)^{\sqrt{x}}}=?$$

---

let :

$$f(x):=\dfrac{x^{\sqrt{\ln x}}\cdot(\sqrt{\ln x})^x}{(\sqrt{x})^{\ln x}\cdot(\ln x)^{\sqrt{x}}}$$

now :

$$\ln (f(x))=\ln (\dfrac{x^{\sqrt{\ln x}}\cdot(\sqrt{\ln x})^x}{(\sqrt{x})^{\ln x}\cdot(\ln x)^{\sqrt{x}}})$$

So :

$$\ln (f(x)) = \sqrt{\ln x}(\ln x) +x\ln(\sqrt{\ln x})-\big( \ln x \ln (\sqrt{ x})+\sqrt{ x} \ln (\ln x)\big)$$

$$\ln (f(x)) = \sqrt{\ln x}(\ln x) +1/2x\ln(\ln x)-\big(1/2 \ln x \ln ( x)+\sqrt{ x} \ln (\ln x)\big)$$

now what ?

Comment: There is $+$ or $\cdot$ in the denominator?

Comment: i'm sorry . I edited .

Answer (score 1):

Use *equivalents* and  simplify your expression:
$$\ln\bigl(f(x)\bigr)=\bigl(\ln x)^{\tfrac32}+\frac12 x\ln(\ln x)-\frac12(\ln x)^2-\sqrt x\ln\bigl(\ln x\bigr)$$
Now we have $$\bigl(\ln x)^{\tfrac32}\prec\ln x)^2\prec\sqrt x\ln\bigl(\ln x\bigr)\prec x\ln(\ln x),  $$
so that 
$$\ln\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\sim_\infty \frac12 x\ln(\ln x)\to+\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

From your last equation
$$\ln (f(x)) = \sqrt{\ln x}(\ln x) +1/2x\ln(\ln x)-\big(1/2 \ln x \ln ( x)+\sqrt{ x} \ln (\ln x)\big)$$ 
write
$$x\ln(\ln x)\left(\frac{1}{\ln(\ln x)}\cdot\frac{(\ln x)^{3/2}}{x} +\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\ln(\ln x)}\cdot\frac{(\ln x)^{2}}{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{ x}}\right)\to x\ln(\ln x)\cdot\frac{1}{2}\to\infty$$